# PHP String Comparison not working as expected

Tags: php, fwrite, fputs

I have the following snippet of code that I am trying to use to read a file that can have some lines repeated two or more times. The goal of this script is to only write unique lines (no duplicates) but for some reason it appears that it is not detecting equality. Any thoughts?

```
$handle = @fopen("Old.csv", "r");
$new = @fopen("New.csv", "w");
$last_line = null;

if ($handle && $new) {
    while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
        if( $last_line != $buffer ) fwrite( $new, $buffer );
        $last_line = $buffer;
    }
    if (!feof($handle)) {
        echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
    }
    fclose($handle);
    fclose($new);
}
```

Here is an example of "Old.csv"

```
 apple
 apple
 orange
 grapes
 grapes
 grapes
```

"New.csv" should be:

```
apple
orange
grapes
```

But it ends up being an exact copy of "Old.csv".

Comment: why not simply `uniq Old.csv > New.csv` at your average unix prompt?

Comment: logic apearrs to be sound... can you confirm that the Old.csv is sorted?

Comment: I edited my original post. The whole purpose of writing the new file is so that duplicate lines would not be written.

Comment: Don't forget about whitespace, encoding, special characters, filetypes, permissions, all the usuals

Comment: I just tested it on my server (PHP 5), and after getting the permissions correct, it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `cat old.csv | sort -u > new.csv` at the command prompt its much faster.

Comment: I'm NOT trying to sort the data. I am trying to remove duplicate lines.

Comment: After getting the line endings correct, your answer did work for pruning out the duplicates so I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone to replied. I did unintentionally leave out a clue which is that I am on a Mac. I resaved the CSV to use the Windows format and re-ran my script and all is well. I guess it was the line endings. Anyhow, the bottom line is that the script works.